# Refactoring multiple if-else

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm performing a business logic but the way I have implemented it, looks a bit convoluted and makes unit testing harder. How do I break down this logic into easier unit-testable tiny methods?

```
public async Task<ResultTypes> ValidatePinAsync(int id, string pin)
{
    ICustomer customer = await _repository.GetCustomer(id);

    if (customer.PinDisabled)
        return ResultTypes.PinDisabled;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.PinNumber))
    {
        customer.PinNumber = customer.DoB.ToString();

        //perform repository call to update PIN here?

        if (customer.PinNumber == pin)
        {
            return ResultTypes.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            //perform repository call to update failure count and then return disabled or invalid
            return ResultTypes.InvalidPinEntered;
        }
    }

    if (customer.PinNumber == pin)
    {
        return ResultTypes.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        //perform repository call to update failure count and then return disabled or invalid
    }

    return ResultTypes.Success;
}
```

Comment: Just removing the first `if (customer.PinNumber == pin) ... else ...` would help -- no need to have it twice

Comment: That was excellent. I'll do that. Is there no way to avoid all the if-else conditionals? I read that having too many is a code smell. I kinda want this to be perfect.

Comment: "_I read that having too many is a code smell. I kinda want this to be perfect._" Here is the thing: Do you want to write _readable_ code or do you want to write [_clever_](https://guifroes.com/clever-code-is-bad/) code? Put differently, how would you quantify "too many"? Is it like "_6 `if` statements in a method is a code smell, but 3 `if` statements in a method is a-okay_"? That would not make any sense. Sure, get rid of redundant things, but in my opinion don't try to write clever code...

Comment: There is no such thing as a "perfect code". The code must be good enough to meet business requirements. Your code is just good enough and easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code a little (as per @canton7's suggestion) to leaf only 3 if statements, none of wich are nested. The logic inside the `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.PinNumber))` could be moved to it's own method.

```
public async Task<ResultTypes> ValidatePinAsync(int id, string pin)
{
    ICustomer customer = await _repository.GetCustomer(id);

    if (customer.PinDisabled)
        return ResultTypes.PinDisabled;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.PinNumber))
    {
        customer.PinNumber = customer.DoB.ToString();
        //perform repository call to update PIN here?
    }

    if (customer.PinNumber != pin)
    {
        //perform repository call to update failure count and then return disabled or invalid
        return ResultTypes.InvalidPinEntered
    }

    return ResultTypes.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check `customer.PinNumber == pin` twice. You need one block to update the pin number from the database if it's empty, and then once you're sure you have it, you can evaluate it:

```cs
public async Task<ResultTypes> ValidatePinAsync(int id, string pin)
{
    ICustomer customer = await _repository.GetCustomer(id);

    if (customer.PinDisabled)
        return ResultTypes.PinDisabled;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.PinNumber))
    {
        customer.PinNumber = customer.DoB.ToString();

        //perform repository call to update PIN here?
    }

    // Now that customer.PinNumber is definitely initialized, it can be evaluated:

    if (customer.PinNumber == pin)
    {
        return ResultTypes.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        //perform repository call to update failure count and then return disabled or invalid
    }

    return ResultTypes.Success;
}
```